# Save location/position of draggable div in jCookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a toolbar on my website, which is draggable. However if a user refreshes/leaves the current page, the toolbar is back at its starting point. I've tried a couple of things, like saving the X/Y position in a cookie, but without succes (Due to a lack of jQuery/Javascript knowledge).

This is what i've tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var postoolbar = $.jCookies({ get : 'postoolbar' });//Get toolbar position

$(function() {
    $( "#toolbar" ).css("margin-left", $('#posX > span').text(xPos));
    $( "#toolbar" ).css("margin-top", $('#posy > span').text(yPos));
});


//Draggable toolbar
$(function() {
    $( "#toolbar" ).draggable(
        {
            drag: function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;
                $('#posX > span').text(xPos);
                $('#posY > span').text(yPos);
            },

            stop: function(event, ui) {

                $.jCookies({ //Create location toolbar cookie
                    name : 'postoolbar',
                    value : { xPos : $('#posX > span').text(xPos), yPos : $('#posY > span').text(yPos)},
                    hours: 3
                });

            }

        }

  );

});

});
```

Retrieving the cookie:

```
var postoolbar = $.jCookies({ get : 'postoolbar' });//Get toolbar position
```

stops my draggable jQuery.

I'm also pretty sure I've done the CSS wrong.

I hope you can help me out :)

Comment: Are you sure that you have the jCookies extension loaded.  What appears in the console when you load the page, and when you click to set the cookie?  Have you validated that the cookie is actually being set?

Comment: I get this error: "TypeError: $.jCookies is not a function" On the line where i retrieve the cookie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've got it working, didn't use jCookies however.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ReadxPos = readCookie('Cookie_Toolbar_PosX')
var ReadyPos = readCookie('Cookie_Toolbar_PosY')
$( "#toolbar" ).css("margin-left", ReadxPos + 'px');
$( "#toolbar" ).css("margin-top", ReadyPos + 'px');

//Draggable toolbar
$(function() {
    $( "#toolbar" ).draggable(
        {
            drag: function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;
                $('#posX > span').text(xPos);
                $('#posY > span').text(yPos);
            },

            stop: function(event, ui) {
              var offset = $(this).offset();
              var xPos = offset.left;
              var yPos = offset.top;
              createCookie('Cookie_Toolbar_PosX', xPos, 0)
              createCookie('Cookie_Toolbar_PosY', yPos, 0)
            }

        }

  );

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it appears that you do not have the jCookie extension installed.

You can download if from [GitHub](https://github.com/tomgrohl/jQuery-plugins/tree/master/jcookie/script).  You should save the `jquery.jcookie.min.js` file on your server and load it immediately after you load jQuery.

Looks like this extension was designed for jQuery 1.6.2, so if it is loaded, but you are still seeing errors, try matching your jQuery version.

When you set your cookie, you should remove the xPos and yPos variables from .text().  This is because you have already set these values, you now just want to read them.

```
value : { xPos : $('#posX > span').text(), yPos : $('#posY > span').text()}
```

Once you have retrieved the cookie then you will need to use the cookie data to set the menu position with something like.

```
$( "#toolbar" ).css("margin-left", postToolbar.xPos + 'px');
$( "#toolbar" ).css("margin-top", postToolbar.yPos + 'px');
```

Comment: As far as I know its linked correctly. I'm using this one: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/04/j-is-for-jcookies-http-cookie-handling-for-jquery/ and its linked like this: <script src="js/jcookies.js"></script>

Comment: Can you post a link to your page, or the <head> HTML?

Comment: I'm running it on a localhost a.t.m. Might be a conflict but that wouldnt be my first guess. This is what's in my <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/Javascript.js"></script>
<script src="js/jcookies.js"></script>

Comment: Try calling jQuery UI after you have called jQuery.

Comment: Alright I've made the changes, didn't know this was necessary. This didn't help for my problem but I'm sure it fixed some problems in the near future, thanks for your replies ;)

Comment: You don't need to call `js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js` *and* `js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js` - they are the same code, just that the latter is compressed.  Remove one or the other to see if that helps